# How to complete the lesson?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have tried to complete lesson 8 ActionScript 3.0 for Adobe Flash Professional 
    CS5, but have find some difficulties:I have enter all codes like shown in the book, but
    not  get the result and I think the problem is that I am working with Adobe Flash CS 6,
    because some parts of files not properly opens in CS 6. Here is the code of lesson 8 
    and what I need to do to complete the lesson?

```
import fl.text.TLFTextField;
import fl.controls.UIScrollBar;
var t:TLFTextField = new TLFTextField();
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
t.width = 500;
t.height = 600;
t.background = true;
t.paddingTop = 20;
t.paddingLeft = 20;
t.paddingRight = 20;
addChild(t);
var textLoad:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
textLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, textLoaded);
textLoad.load(new URLRequest("sample.txt"));
function textLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var txt:String = URLLoader(e.target).data as String;
    t.text = txt;
    tf.color = 0x336633;
    tf.font = "Arial";
    tf.size = 14;
    t.setTextFormat(tf);
}
var formatClip:Formatter = new Formatter();
var showFormat:Boolean = true;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, showFormatter);
function showFormatter(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode == 70)
    {
        if (showFormat)
        {
            addChild(formatClip);
            formatClip.x = t.width;
            formatClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
            showFormat = false;
        }
        else
        {
            formatClip.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
            removeChild(formatClip);
            showFormat = true;
        }
    }
}
function drag(e:Event):void
{
    formatClip.startDrag();
    formatClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, noDrag);
}
function noDrag(e:Event):void
{
    formatClip.stopDrag();
}
formatClip.fontList.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, setFont);
formatClip.fontSizer.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, setFontSize);
formatClip.colorPicker.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, setColor);
formatClip.columnNum.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, setColumns);
function setFont(e:Event):void
{
    tf.font = e.target.selectedItem.label;
    t.setTextFormat(tf);
}

function setFontSize(e:Event):void
{
    tf.size = e.target.value;
    t.setTextFormat(tf);
}

function setColor(e:Event):void
{
    tf.color = e.target.selectedColor;
    t.setTextFormat(tf);
}
function setColumns(e:Event):void
{
    t.columnCount = e.target.value;
}
var scroller:UIScrollBar = new UIScrollBar();
scroller.move(t.x + t.width, t.y );
scroller.height = t.height;
scroller.scrollTarget = t;
addChild(scroller);
scroller.visible = false;
formatClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setScrollbar);
function setScrollbar(e:Event):void
{
    if (t.textHeight > scroller.height)
    {
        scroller.visible = true;
    }
    else
    { 
        scroller.visible = false;
    }
    t.scrollV = 1;
}
```

I get this swf:

[image]

But need to get this swf:
 [image]
 Thank you
 Juozas Vitkus

Comment: lesson 8? book? what are you talking about?!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use a multiline textfield

just add `t.multiline=true;`